# Hololens Video recording not showing UI elements

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, video-capture, hololens, mrtk

We're working with the Hololens 2 and sadly when recording a video, taking an image or going into the live-view, Unity UI elements are not shown in the image/video.

Does anybody know how we can make Unity UI elements appear in video & photo capture in Hololens?

Here is an example where below the title there is text present, but not captured in the image.

[image: Image of UI window with missing text below title]

The title part uses a `TextMeshPro` component, while the text part uses a `TextMeshProUGUI` component (due to the scrolling window of the text.)

We're using Unity 2020.3.6f1, MRTK 2.7.2 with OpenXR backend.

Thanks for any help and recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that our Unity version was not updated, as hinted out in this github issue. Simply updating to the newest Unity version solved the problem.
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/10155

Answer (score 0):

For how to create mixed-reality photos and videos, you can use the Start gesture to go to Start, then select the Camera icon, for more information please refer to this link: [Create mixed reality photos and videos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/holographic-photos-and-videos).

If you want to seamlessly integrate mixed reality capture and insertion into your apps, you need to enable the [Windows Mixed Reality Camera Settings provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/camera-system/windows-mixed-reality-camera-settings?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#enabling-the-windows-mixed-reality-camera-settings-provider) in your MRTK profile and check [Render from PV Camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/camera-system/windows-mixed-reality-camera-settings?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#render-mixed-reality-capture-from-the-photovideo-camera).

Comment: Hey @Herbando, thanks for your answer. We already use/implemented the described functionalities (hence how we took the image above). the main question is why a TextMeshProUGUI component is not rendered anymore when capturing such an image/video. Do you know a solution to that?

Comment: According to the latest information show in the MRTK commit: [Improve PV camera version messages](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/10077). The Mixed Reality Capture feature only has been verified on legacy XR and Windows XR Plugin backend for now.
For your issue is specifically limited to when using OpenXR, could you file this issue on the MRTK issue page? So that, you can track it in the GitHub project, since that is where the issue updates would be coming once we get something further to share.